# Usar useEffect toda vez que meu location.pathname for alterado

Tags: react, react-router-dom

Eu possuo uma variável chamada nameScreen que eu preciso alterar seu valor toda vez que o `location.path` for alterado (sempre que houver uma alteração de rota):

```
<Typography variant="h6" noWrap>
    {nameScreen}
</Typography>
```

Eu tentei algo como:

```
const [nameScreen, setNameScreen] = useState('')

const location = useLocation();

useEffect(() => {
    changeTitleHeader()
        // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
},[location.pathname])

  const changeTitleHeader = () => {
      if (location.pathname === '/home') {
        setNameScreen('Welcome to home!')
      }
      else if(location.pathname === '/users') {
          setNameScreen('Users')
      }
      else if(location.pathname === '/companies') {
        setNameScreen('Companies')
      }
  }
```

Eu preciso que toda vez que o meu location.pathname for alterado, minha variável nameScreen altere o seu valor com base no nome da rota.

Meu `useEffect()` não está sendo chamado novamente quando o `location.pathname` é alterado. Como posso corrigir isso?

Answer (score 0):

O `location.pathname` não é uma variável de estado do componente mas, se você precisa que todas as vezes que o componente receber alguma alteração ele recupere algum valor não passe nada para o `array` do `useEffect`, ***exemplo***:

```js
function Source() {
  const [st, setSt] = React.useState(new Date().toString());
  React.useEffect(() => {
    (() => {
      setSt(new Date().toString());
    })()
  });
  return (
    <h1>{st}</h1>
  );
}
function App() {
  const [input, setInput] = React.useState('');
  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" value={input} onChange={e => setInput(e.target.value)} />
      <Source />
    </div>
  );
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

verifique que todas vezes que digitar no `input` a data e hora são recuperados. A lógica no seu código é a mesma, não passe nada no `useEffect`, o complicado é saber se o que está fazendo é a melhor solução, talvez não seja.